# OSX 10.10.2 Airplay to ATV (A1469) doesn't wotk

Tags: macos, mac, appletv, airplay

Here is what I have:

Macbook air (MacBookAir3,2) running 10.10.2
Apple TV (A1469) 3rd gen

I have airplayed my iPad to my TV numerous times so I know it works. However, airplay does not even show up as a display option on my mac.

I have been hunting on the net for an hour and it isn't clear that it simply isn't supported by my mac.

So: Can anyone tell me how to do this or conclusively state it isn't possible/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Apple's documentation](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201343#requirements), you must use a MacBook Air from mid-2011 or later to get AirPlay functionality from your AppleTV.  The model you list (MacBookAir3,2) is showing as a model from late 2010.  So, no, AirPlay won't be possible for you.